# Upgrade AWS RDS PostgreSQL from 10.18 to 13.4 using terraform

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform

I am blocked while upgrading AWS RDS PostgreSQL from 10.18 to 13.4 using terraform. Below is the TF code used and errors. Pl suggest.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aws_rds_cluster_instance" {
  count                        = 3
  identifier                   = "aws_rds_cluster_instance-${count.index}"
  instance_class               = "db.r4.large"
  availability_zone            = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  engine                       = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version               = aws_rds_cluster.aws_rds_cluster.engine_version
  cluster_identifier           = aws_rds_cluster.aws_rds_cluster.id
  monitoring_interval          = "60"
  monitoring_role_arn          = "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/role"
  performance_insights_enabled = "true"
  preferred_maintenance_window = "mon:12:20-mon:12:50"
  promotion_tier               = "1"
  publicly_accessible          = "false"
  db_subnet_group_name         = aws_db_subnet_group.db.name
  tags = merge(map(
    "system", "local.system_name",
    "business_unit", "local.business_unit",
  ), local.base_tags)

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [engine_version]
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aws_rds_cluster" {
  engine                              = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version                      = "10.18"
  cluster_identifier                  = "aws_rds_cluster_instance-cluster"
  availability_zones                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  database_name                       = "aws_rds_cluster_instance"
  deletion_protection                 = true
  master_username                     = var.db_username
  master_password                     = var.db_password
  backup_retention_period             = 7
  preferred_backup_window             = "07:00-08:00"
  preferred_maintenance_window        = "mon:23:00-mon:23:30"
  port                                = 5432
  skip_final_snapshot                 = "true"
  storage_encrypted                   = "true"
  iam_database_authentication_enabled = "true"
  kms_key_id                          = aws_kms_key.key.arn
  vpc_security_group_ids              = [aws_security_group.db.id]
  db_subnet_group_name                = aws_db_subnet_group.db.name
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name     = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.param_group.name
  tags = merge(map(
    "system", "local.system_name",
    "business_unit", "local.business_unit",
  ), local.base_tags)

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [engine_version]
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I am getting below error after changing engine version and parameter group values.

```
Error: Failed to modify RDS Cluster (aws_rds_cluster_instance): InvalidParameterCombination: The AllowMajorVersionUpgrade flag must be present when upgrading to a new major version.
    status code: 400, request id: 648f75a8-abcd-49be-z480-056e71e86e6c

  on main.tf line 62, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aws_rds_cluster":
  62: resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aws_rds_cluster" {
```

When we have added allow_major_version_upgrade = true under resource aws_rds_cluster_instance/aws_rds_cluster I have got below error

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aws_rds_cluster_instance":
  49:   allow_major_version_upgrade = true

An argument named "allow_major_version_upgrade" is not expected here.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 63, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aws_rds_cluster":
  63:   allow_major_version_upgrade = true

An argument named "allow_major_version_upgrade" is not expected here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allow_major_version_upgrade` argument belongs to the schema in the `aws_rds_cluster` resource. Since the error thrown states it is unsupported, that means your version of the provider is too old to support that argument.

First upgrade the AWS provider to a minimum of 3.8.0, which is the [first version supporting that argument](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#380-september-24-2020).

Then, you can supply that argument and value to the resource as expected:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aws_rds_cluster" {
  allow_major_version_upgrade = true
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the provider to 3.8.0 and changed the engine version to 13.4 with a new parameter group name of 13 version. TF init and TF apply took around 10s for modifications. But when I looked at the engine version in RDS AWS console, it still shows up 10.18.